# Change a select list display value upon selecting description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectlist

I would like a select list that does the following:

1. When the select list is open, display the list of descriptions.
2. When the user selects an item, the select list will close an only the value will be displayed.

The reason for this is to conserve space as the values will be much shorter. I'm hoping that there's an answer in jQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: So you have an option like `<option value="Cheesy">Dangerously Cheesy</option>`. When the list is closed, the selected item should just show the "Cheesy" value, but when they click on the dropdown, the options they select from will show "Dangerously Cheesy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've worked it out:

```
$("#selectList").focus(function() {
  var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
  selectedOption.text(selectedOption.attr("description"));
});

$("#selectList").change(function() {
  var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
  selectedOption.attr("description", selectedOption.text());
  selectedOption.text(selectedOption.val());
});

var currSelOption = $("#selectList").find("option:selected");
currSelOption.attr("description", currSelOption .text());
currSelOption.text(currSelOption .val());
```

It could probably be optimized a bit.

Comment: Please note two things with the above code:
1. There is an issue when the user selects the same value twice. Since the select list is not actually changing, only the focus event would be triggered.
2. When manipulating select lists, IE will reset the state of the select list to be closed. The user would need to select the list twice.