# Change selected item's text to include its parent optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` element which will be displayed on mobile device

```
<form>
<select id="selectMe" >
    <optgroup label="Australia">
        <option value="AustCars">Australia Cars Report</option>
        <option value="AustBikes">Australia Bikes Report</option>                
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="New Zealand">                    
        <option value="NZCars">New Zealand Cars Report</option>
        <option value="NZBikes">New Zealand Bikes Report</option>                
    </optgroup>
</select>
</form>​
```

Two things to note:

- I want to display the full name `Australia Cars Report` when closed, to remove the ambiguity between Australia and New Zealand.
- I want to use the shorter version `Cars Report` when the `select` is opened, because the full name `Australia Cars Report` is too long for the iPhone selector (not actual names, but renders as `Austr...rs Report` or similar) and the country is implicit in the `optgroup`.

My approach (based on [Change a select list display value upon selecting description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791754/change-a-select-list-display-value-upon-selecting-description)) is to modify the value of each item when the control gets focus, and then un-modify when it loses focus. And that's about where I get stuck.

I have two problems here:

- I can get the focus event, but there's not 'lostfocus' event. I can't use the 'changed' event because the user might not have actually changed the selection.
- I don't know how to get the value of the `optgroup` to add and remove from the option text. By this I mean that I need to find, for `Australia Cars Report`, that it is nested under `Australia` and thus I can remove that word from the display text.

I can use javascript or jQuery, or other tools if applicable. Open to suggestions of an easy way to do this that I've overlooked, too.

Comment: "there's not 'lostfocus' event" --- `blur`. And the second question is not clear enough

Comment: I've tried to clarify the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can get the focus event, but there's not 'lostfocus' event. I can't use the 'changed' event because the user might not have actually changed the selection.

Use `blur`.

> I don't know how to get the value of the optgroup to add and remove from the option text.

A little unclear, but I'll hazard a few guesses to get you started:

- You'll need to give the specific group an ID to access it uniquely, e.g.

  `var fooElement = document.getElementById("foo")`
- You can get the selected object using `fooElement.selected`
- You can get all of the options using `fooElement.options[]`.  Adding and removing new DOM elements to this list will add or remove them in the HTML DOM.
- Values of an `option` can be found using `.value` or `.text`.

Try looking up the `select` tag in HTML, and the javascript to interact with that type of element. Good luck.

Comment: No problem, shooting in the dark is fun sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

For 1st question: see Steve's response.

For 2nd Question:
You can add the text Australia to option when it gets blurred

```
$("select").blur(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).parent().html() + " " + $(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the heads up on the `.parent()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selectMe option').click(function(){
    var myparent = $(this).parent();
    if (myparent.get(0).tagName == 'OPTGROUP'){
        $(this).text(myparent.attr('label') + ' ' + $(this).text());
    }
});

$('#selectMe').focus(function(){
    $('option', this).each(function(){
        var myparent = $(this).parent();    
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(myparent.attr('label'),''));     
    });
})
```

working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/GXvJB/11/